# cp: cannot stat No such file or directory

Tags: linux

I'm trying to install Haptic Device SDK in Ubuntu 16.04 STL (64-bit). The installation process is trivial. It is just running `sudo ./install` but I get these issues

```
COPYING SYSTEM FILES
cp: cannot stat '/home/smsh/Documents/Phantom': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat 'Omni': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat 'Drivers/openhaptics_3.4-0-developer-edition-amd64/opt/*': No such file or directory
```

The install file is

```
#!/bin/bash -e
# Check if user has root privileges or running as root. 

if [ "$EUID" -ne 0 ]
  then echo "Please run as root"
  exit
fi
#Get location of the the script file. 
SOURCE="${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
while [ -h "$SOURCE" ]; do # resolve $SOURCE until the file is no longer a symlink
  DIR="$( cd -P "$( dirname "$SOURCE" )" && pwd )"
  SOURCE="$(readlink "$SOURCE")"
  [[ $SOURCE != /* ]] && SOURCE="$DIR/$SOURCE" # if $SOURCE was a relative symlink, we need to resolve it relative to the path where the symlink file was located
done
DIR="$( cd -P "$( dirname "$SOURCE" )" && pwd )"

# Print Warning
echo ""
echo -n "THE COMPUTER MUST REBOOT AFTER THE INSTALLATION IN ORDER FOR THE SOFTWARE TO WORK PROPERLY. PLEASE SAVE ANY OPEN FILES OTHERWISE YOU WILL LOSE UNSAVED DATA."
echo ""
echo ""
echo "** Please make sure that you have installed the following dependencies before compiling OpenHaptics applications:"
echo "  - ncurses  (libncurses5-dev)"
echo "  - freeglut (freeglut3)"
echo "  - build-essential"
echo ""
echo ""
while :
do
    echo "The software will be installed to path : /opt/OpenHaptics/Developer/3.4-0/"   
    echo "Do you want to continue? (y/n): "
    read con
    echo ""

    if [ "$con" = "y" -o "$con" = "Y" ]; then
        
        
        #copy files to opt folder
        echo "COPYING SYSTEM FILES"
        
        sudo cp -R $DIR/opt/* /opt
        sudo cp -R $DIR/usr/lib/* /usr/lib
        sudo cp -R $DIR/usr/include/* /usr/include

        #Create symbolic links
        echo ""

        ln -sfn /usr/lib/libHD.so.3.4.0 /usr/lib/libHD.so.3.4
        ln -sfn /usr/lib/libHD.so.3.4.0 /usr/lib/libHD.so

        ln -sfn /usr/lib/libHL.so.3.4.0 /usr/lib/libHL.so.3.4
        ln -sfn /usr/lib/libHL.so.3.4.0 /usr/lib/libHL.so

        ln -sfn /usr/lib/libQH.so.3.4.0 /usr/lib/libQH.so.3.4
        ln -sfn /usr/lib/libQH.so.3.4.0 /usr/lib/libQH.so

        ln -sfn /usr/lib/libQHGLUTWrapper.so.3.4.0 /usr/lib/libQHGLUTWrapper.so.3.4
        ln -sfn /usr/lib/libQHGLUTWrapper.so.3.4.0 /usr/lib/libQHGLUTWrapper.so
        
        sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/OpenHaptics

        echo "DONE!"
        echo ""
        
        #Set path for OH_SDK_BASE

        echo -n "SETTING ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES ..... "
            echo "export OH_SDK_BASE=/opt/OpenHaptics/Developer/3.4-0" > /etc/profile.d/openhaptics.sh

        echo "DONE!"
        echo ""
        echo "IMPORTANT NOTE: The following dependencies are needed to compile OpenHaptics SDK examples. Please make sure they are installed on your system. "
        echo "1. freeglut3-dev"
        echo "2. libncurses5-dev"
        echo "3. zlib1g-dev"

        echo "Please reboot the computer before using Geomagic Touch Device Driver software. "
        echo "Press ANY key to RESTART now or 'q' to cancel" 

        read d

        if [ "$d" = "q" -o "$d" = "Q" ]; then
            echo ""
            echo "Restart aborted."
            echo ""
            echo "Please reboot the computer before using Openhaptics SDK. "
            echo ""
            break
        else
            echo ".... restarting"

            sudo reboot
            
        fi

    elif [ "$con" = "n" -o "$con" = "N" ]; then
        echo "Installation aborted."
        echo ""
        break
    else
        echo "Invalid key."
        echo ""
    fi
done

#install
```

I've installed the following tools

```
ncurses  (libncurses5-dev)
freeglut (freeglut3)
build-essential
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move to a directory without spaces, tabs or newlines in the name.

```
sudo cp -R $DIR/opt/* /opt
```

`DIR` is split on whitespaces, it should be quoted.

```
sudo cp -R "$DIR"/opt/* /opt
```

Comment: `Move to a directory without spaces` solved the problem. Thank you. Is this a sloppy script or this is the way Linux works?

Comment: I would say both. This is a sloppy script. There are many sloppy scripts and languages in the wild, so one has to be cautious for odd characters in filenames (like spaces, newlines, tabs and `;`).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `bash -c "command"` instead of just `command`